# union couple of text boxes to one model property

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Assuming the user sees 2 text box (for example one is date, second is begin hour). Is there a way to join them in the cshtml to be represented as one model property ?

**View**:

```
<input type="text" name="OrderDate"  id="OrderDate" class="datepicker" />
<input type="text" name="OrderTime"  id="OrderTime" />
```

**Model**:

```
public class OrderDetails
{        
   public DateTime OrderDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´d do it with a ViewModel, in order to keep things more ordered.

**Model**:

```
public class OrderDetailsViewModel
{

    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public int OrderTime { get; set; }
    //this is the field you use to have your data together
    public DateTime OrderDateTime { 
    get {
      OderTime.AddHours(OrderDateTime);
      return OderTime;
    } set; }
}
```

**View**:

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.OrderDate , new { @class = "datepicker", @id="OrderDate" })
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.OrderTime , new { @id="OrderTime " })
```

Comment: Glad to help. Verify the part where you set the hours to your final Datetime, the way I did it just add the hours, rather to set them.